# Google Cloud Alert Policies - Include Error Message Within Documentation Body

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-monitoring

I can't seem to find much information on this one. I have a requirement to include the error message body in the email alert that is sent out when the GCP alert policy is triggered.

Now I can see from the [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables?_ga=2.134994033.-1877692169.1622191116&_gac=1.262476286.1629454275.Cj0KCQjwpf2IBhDkARIsAGVo0D1xR1bfV5-k7F54lwx-GxU7jul6Dbw9fXscB66CJ44jE2ElFqvjirQaAg9LEALw_wcB) that certain variables can be added relating to the policy itself but does anyone know of any easy way to parse the log contents failure payload and pass it? This may be a failure of understanding on my part.

What I have tried is to setup a cloud function that raises an error with a specific message whenever the http request is made. I have setup a policy on the logs for this function that trigger for the error severity. This works fine but what I can't do is parse the error message in the email alert body. Does anyone know of a good work around for this or am I missing something?

Comment: You have created a log-based alert policy and couldn't find a way to include the error message from those logs in the Alert notification email sent to you, is that your issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, has anyone been able to resolve this? Though in my case I just made a direct alert via logging trigger, so it looks out for a specific log criteria and then sends out an alert if it finds it, but I'm unable to include anything useful in the email for it...

Comment: I can definitely answer it but before spending any time, is the OP still active here?

Comment: @PraveenTiwari The bounty was not started by OP, it was started by someone else who is presently active.